# Lightbox for Footer in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, footer, lightbox

Extremely long story short, I need help on how to use a lightbox plugin for the footer links in my wordpress theme... I know there are many lightbox plugins that are free, which is great. Now I just need to know how to make those links' content appear in the lightbox...currently they open in a new page and this is no good because I do not want them to navigate away from the page.

There is just simple info in these links such as terms and conditions, contact info etc

Thank you.

Comment: Unless this question is purely code-related, you're better off asking over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Never even knew that website existed. Thank you for the heads up!